# Fetch email using JavaxMail and Proxies

Tags: java, proxy, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm trying to connect to a mail server using IMAP protocol and proxies with the JavaxMail library. Yet they seem not to work.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
Host host = Host.getHostByMail(mail);

properties.put("proxySet", "true");
properties.put("mail.imap.proxy.host", "proxy host");
properties.put("mail.imap.proxy.port", "proxy port");
properties.put("mail.imap.proxy.user", "proxy user");
properties.put("mail.imap.proxy.password", "proxy passwd");

properties.put("mail.imap.host", host.toString());
properties.put("mail.imap.port", "143");
properties.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
Store store = emailSession.getStore("imap");
store.connect(host.toString(), mail, passwd);
Folder readOnly = store.getFolder("INBOX");
readOnly.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
```

When I try to use this code it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-2" com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to 
host, port: imap.tiscali.it, 143; timeout -1; Using web proxy host, port: proxy_host, proxy_port; nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: connection through proxy proxy_host:proxy_port to imap.tiscali.it:143 failed: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:740)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
at mail.MailHandler.readMail(MailHandler.java:97)
at mail.MailHandler.readAllMail(MailHandler.java:143)
at mail.MailSender.onCall(MailSender.java:27)
at commands.Temp$1.run(Temp.java:21)
at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:566)
at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:516)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connection through proxy proxy_host:proxy_port to imap.tiscali.it:143 failed: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.proxyConnect(SocketFetcher.java:877)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:354)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:134)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:131)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.newIMAPProtocol(IMAPStore.java:763)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:698)
... 8 more
```

This happens when I use HTTP/HTTPS proxies, but when I use SOCKS proxies it gives

```
Connection dropped by server?
```

Comment: Does tiscali support connecting via a proxy?

Comment: Also, [this](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#proxy) could be of use

Comment: Thanks @g00se but this problem happens with every mail I try to connect to

Comment: Is the proxy server configured to let through connections on port 143?  Some are configured only to allow connections to web ports.

Comment: @Max I'm using IpRoyal

Comment: That doesn’t answer the question. The proxy is giving you a 403 meaning it won’t allow you to connect with it; maybe you need proxy credentials, maybe it doesn’t support 143. You’ll need to consult your proxy documentation/admin/etc.

Comment: Proxy credentials I don't think so because I have the credentials, and I can even whitelist IPs. The fact is that I don't know if the error is from the server or from the proxy

Comment: It is from the proxy. IMAP doesn’t use HTTP, therefore the HTTP error must be from the HTTP proxy.

Comment: when I use SOCKS proxy it still gives me an error

Comment: In addition, Tiscali says you should use port 993 with TLS, not 143 with starttls: https://assistenza.tiscali.it/servizi/guida/parametri-mail/

Comment: Then please provide the error you get with the socks server too. “I got an error” doesn’t help anyone.

Comment: It says connection dropped by the server... The only change I made is the port since the hostname is the same

Comment: Did you change it to TLS instead of starttls?  These are different things.

Comment: you mean chaning mail.imaps.starttls.enable to mail.imaps.tls.enable? Because the error is still the same (Remote host terminated the handshake;)